# change the vertical distance between lines inside an enumerate

Tags: margins, enumerate

I want to know how to use a command like `\enumerate` but more compact. Here's an example:

[image]

I'm writing this problem using \enumerate. In this way:

```
Let $\sP$ be a property of morphisms of schemes such that:

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]

\item A closed immersion has $\sP$
\item A composition of two morphisms having $\sP$ has $\sP$

\end{enumerate}
```

And this is how it looks:

[image]

A simple way to solve the problem is to avoid enumerate and use the command `\newline`. I want to know if there is a better solution for this using some enumerator, itemize or related command. (I always prefer to have all my problems indexed via commands and not by hand)

EDIT: I put minimal examples.

Comment: Full minimal example please. Also see the `enumitem` package

Comment: Just give \itemsep=2pt (whatever number) next to \begin{enumerate}[(a)] to reduce the space between the items

Comment: It is the option `noitemsep` if you load the `enumitem` package.

Comment: My suggestion works if you load enumerate package

Answer (score 3):

This could be achieved either using `enumerate` package, setting `itemsep` value or for example with the more sophisticated `enumitem` package,  generally (`\setlist` macro) or individually at the right position. However, it might be necessary, to reduce the `topsep` value which is responsible for vertical spacing above (and below) the whole enumeration block.

(The `shortlabels` option to `enumitem` allows to emulate `enumerate`, the first value in the key value list of the enumerate options is then interpreted as the labeling style as in `enumerate`. This and some exaggerated values are shown for demonstration purposes in the second example.

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcommand{\sP}{\mathcal{P}}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={(\alph*)},noitemsep,topsep=0.5pt}
\begin{document}
\noindent Let $\sP$ be a property of morphisms of schemes such that:
\begin{enumerate}
\item A closed immersion has $\sP$
\item A composition of two morphisms having $\sP$ has $\sP$
\end{enumerate}
\hrule
\vskip\baselineskip % or some other spacing here

\noindent Let $\sP$ be a property of morphisms of schemes such that: (Exaggerated)
\begin{enumerate}[(A),itemsep=20pt,topsep=50pt]
\item A closed immersion has $\sP$
\item A composition of two morphisms having $\sP$ has $\sP$
\end{enumerate}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

[image]